# Bootstrap popover with grails and ajax

Tags: ajax, grails, twitter-bootstrap, popover

just trying to use ajax formRemote in a BS popover.
A simple form works, but the ajax implementation not:

1)  gsp code

```
    <div id="addfolder">
            <a href="#" class="btn" id="nrfolder" rel="popover">
            <i class="icon-folder-close icon-large"></i></a><%--<g:message code="folder"  args="[entityName]" default="New Folder"/>--%></a>
        </div>
        <div id="newRootFolder" style="display:none;">
        <form class="form-inline" style="width:280px;">
        <g:formRemote name="createRootFolder" url="[controller:'folders',action:'create']" onLoading="showModalSpinnerNewFolder();" onComplete="hideModalSpinnerNewFolder();" onSuccess="doResponseNewFolder(data);" >
              <g:textField  name="folderName" class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="New folder"/>
              <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-info" />
              <a href="#" class="btn"  onclick="$('#nrfolder').popover('hide')"/>Cancel</a>
        </g:formRemote>
</g:formRemote>
    </form>
    </div>
```

2) Popover call with jquery

```
$('#nrfolder').popover({placement:'right',title:'New Root Folder',html:true,content: function() { return $('#newRootFolder').html();} });
```

3) jquery success event: doResponseNewFolder function

```
function doResponseNewFolder(data) {
        alert('toto' + data.success);
        if (data.success == 'true') {
            var msg = data.msg;
            // reload tree view
            $('#tree').dynatree('getTree').reload();
        } else {
            var msg = $('<ul class="errors">');
            for (var i = 0; i < data.errorList.length; i++) {
                msg.append('<li>' + data.errorList[i] + "</li>");
            }
        }
        $('#new_folder_msg').html(msg);
        $('#new_folder_msg').show();
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Could you please post the content of `doResponseNewFolder(data)`? In addition, is your `#newRootFolder` `div` accidently not closed or did you omit pasting the end of it?

Comment: thanks to collaborate, the div is well closed (edited and modified)

Comment: You're welcome, but try to be more accurate the way you code: the HTML you pasted is not valid XML, and this is the first thing to check before testing. Keep in mind that good indentation is a best practice and this will help you avoiding XML syntax errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're messing up with forms, let me explain: Grails' `g:formRemote` is a helper for making ajax web forms, so if you look at the resulting HTML there will be a form generated at the call.

The fact is that you already opened a form, which isn't valid HTML syntax. That first form should not exist. You can give its attributes to your `g:formRemote` though and Grails will pass them to your generated `form`:

```
<g:formRemote class="form-inline" style="width:280px;" name="createRootFolder" url="[controller:'folders',action:'create']" onLoading="showModalSpinnerNewFolder();" onComplete="hideModalSpinnerNewFolder();" onSuccess="doResponseNewFolder(data);" >
      <g:textField  name="folderName" class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="New folder"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-info" />
      <a href="#" class="btn"  onclick="$('#nrfolder').popover('hide')"/>Cancel</a>
</g:formRemote>
```

This, with no other forms imbricated, will be enough.

Comment: Anyway, I still don't understand where you call the `popover` you mentioned and I don't really understand what you want in it: the calling form? (which is the content of `#newRootFolder`)

Comment: popover `content` parameter is `bool|string` [according to its documentation](http://daveyijzermans.nl/jquery/popover/demo.html#parameters_content), so you should make it a string. When you call `popover`, the popover will be loaded unless `trigger` value is `'none'`. What do you really want: popover on form submit?